# unable to connect mysql connector to intellij idea(JDBC problem)

Tags: java, jdbc, jar, mysql-connector

I am facing problem to connect MySQL connector to class path .I am trying to do it on every possible way and I am doing everything right but on command prompt it is constantly showing "class not found". please somebody help me I am facing this issue since last two days.

1. I try convert zip(win rare)file to jar file and
2. I also try solve the problem through control panel

Answer (score -1):

so I faced this a while back, I was using Bluej as the IDE which solved the issue. Any how to connect mysql connector to classpath, we have to give location of jar file in dependency if using IDE, or in command if running directly via terminal.
For IntelliJ IDE, try following [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-external-jar-file-to-an-intellij-idea-project/) and check if it solves the issue.

As for the terminal, you can try
`java.exe -classpath D:\lib*Main script.java`
I created a [README](https://github.com/sarthak-19/Bitnine-Coding-Test/tree/main/Q5) file with explaining basic operations using MYSQL driver. You can check this out if it helps.